# ImageSpan with clickable link

Tags: java, android, android-source

I am building the source of Android so I can customize some classes. That being said I don't have access to an `Activity` to call `startActivity` with an `Intent`.

Heres what I got:

```
Spannable sp = (Spannable) text;
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(mContext, imageResourceId);
sp.setSpan(imageSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Is there a way to open a href or link on click of the `ImageSpan`?

Comment: call another `sp.setSpan` this time with a custom `ClickableSpan`

Comment: I've looked into this. But then what? Theres no way to call `startActivity()` as far as ik

Comment: what do you mean: "But then what"? is `onClick(View widget)` being called?

Comment: How do I tell Android to open a link? I don't have access to an `Activity` object

Comment: did you create a custom `ClickableSpan`? is `onClick` called?

Comment: yes the `onClick` is called but `startActivity()` doesn't exist cause its not in an `Activity`

Comment: use `Context#startActivity`, get the context from somewhere (e,g, from `View widget` parameter or from `mContext`, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

you can create [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) for same region as your ImageSpan and add method `onClick` for clickable span.

Comment: I am changing the `TextView` class and adding this code. I do not have access to any variables to start an activity as far as ik

Comment: there really is no other code. Im just adding this to the `setText` method of `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

If you do use a `ClickableSpan` as suggested, you get a call to [`onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html#onClick(android.view.View)). This callback has a `View` parameter that you can use.

A `View` has a method [`getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) that you can use to obtain a context and call `startActivity`.